# Selenium (PhantomJS) Unicode Chars In URL Altered Error (Python)

Tags: python, selenium, unicode, urlencode, headless-browser

Problem Is Quite Simple; I'm using selenium (specifically the PhantomJS Webdriver) to access a website with the URL `domain.com/something/⑧.txt` for example. Quite straightforward apart from the fact the URL contains the `⑧` character.

Selenium just changes this to a `?` causing the website to return a not found error. Note I'm just using the `driver.get` function.

This is both annoying and confusing, is there anyway to bypass selenium changing the URL without my permission.

Comment: One simple way that I can think of is to just use a URL shortener like [this](https://goo.gl/). This will give your website an alias.

Comment: interesting, But is there some sort of API or library or programmatic way I can do that; you know without an open website.

Comment: Code please. Please see [mcve]. Python 2 or 3? How are you inputting the symbol?

Comment: @MohsinKale You would only need to shorten the URL only once, no? So, either you can embed the shortened URL in your file or use their [API](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/apis/urlshortener/v1) to retrieve the information.

Comment: I didnt include any code because literally all I did was driver.get('url'), seemed kinda pointless; I've tried entering the url several ways and I can assure you the character was there before I passed it to selenium, but afterwards it became a '?'.

Comment: @AdeelAhmad Sure, The API Looks nice so I'll go with it, But I'd still prefer a less convoluted way just to access a single url.